# Sscanf get $ variables

Tags: c

Let's say I have `char ** argv`
and that for every `argv[i]` I'll have a random string but some of them have a env inside, for example:

```
argv[2] = "asdad$HOMEsada";
```

If my home directory is /home/user, how can I get `argv[2]= "asdad/home/usersada";`

*IMPORTANT*: I have to use sscanf and "%[_a-zA-Z0-9]" format.

I have implemented some code that works but doesn't use those options, here it is:

```
    for (int j = 0; argv[j]; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; argv[j][i]; i++)
        {
                if (argv[j][i] == '$')
            {
                char principio[i + 1];
                strncpy(principio, argv[j], i);
                principio[i] = '\0';
                argv[j] = strdup(strcat(principio, getenv(argv[j] + i + 1)));
                break;
            }
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad. You will need to parse the string, then resolve the env variables. Have you written any code to solve it?

Comment: How do you know that the env var is `$HOME` and not `$HOMEsada` or `$HO` or `$HOMEsa`? Normally shells require `{}` in such cases.

Comment: @EugeneSh. I have written some code yes, in fact, it's a functional code XD, the problem is that I'm forced to do it with sscanf and that format

Comment: @Thomas I've actually done what you are asking, the problem is that I need to implement it using sscanf and that format.

Comment: @walter The question would be received much better if you have posted your attempt and pointed to the specific problem you are having.

Comment: @EugeneSh. On it!

Comment: @EugeneSh. Just finished editing the comment to show my code!